# How can I calculate the smallest voltage a given adc can read?

Tags: measurements

I have a project where I'd need to measure small voltage (0.05 mV) output of a wheatstone bridge with an arduino mini pro.

[Based on my previous question most probably it can't be done with its analogue input directly.](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/what-is-the-range-of-the-measurable-relative-elasticity-with-a-commonly-used-str)
[what is the range of the measurable relative elasticity with a commonly used strain gauge](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/what-is-the-range-of-the-measurable-relative-elasticity-with-a-commonly-used-str)

The question is that can a [hx711 module](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/813/hx711_english-1022875.pdf) measure so small voltages? 
Based on the calculation in the question it has the resolution of 3 uV from 0 to 5V excitation voltage.

How can estimate that what resolution I can expect in practice?

Comment: This is a physical design for EMI crosstalk issue and depends on your ability to control impedances low, balance and shield wires.  This might require Coax to your source and careful grounding at a minimum

Comment: Are you asking about measuring voltages with *just* an ADC, or with an ADC plus signal conditioning and amplification?

Comment: With an ADC plus signal conditioning and amplification. Basically with what that hx711 or similar a module (in price) offers.

Comment: What is the price of hx711?

Comment: Around 0.3 - 1 dollars each depending on volume and supplier (Chinese or EU).

Comment: I took a closer look at your question. Can please help us understand how you calculated 3uV resolution? I suggest you update the original post with this information. Since you are using a wheatstone bridge I am assuming you are using Common Mode Voltage.